# Want use output from Watchdog as filename to then open that file

Tags: python, system, watchdog

Im trying to write a simple script that watchs for a (TDMS) file to be saved, then opens the file to retrieve a value.

The watchdog side works fine, and passes the event.src_path to the GET_DATA function. When the file tries to open, I get an error..

"PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\PythonTargetDirectory\example.tdms'"

If I use the filename as an arguement instead, it will open the file and retrieve the data. Surely this means the permissions are correct to be able to open it?

Can some body help please?

```
import nptdms
import numpy
import watchdog.events
import watchdog.observers
import time

class Handler(watchdog.events.PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        # Set the patterns for PatternMatchingEventHandler
        watchdog.events.PatternMatchingEventHandler.__init__(self, patterns=['*.tdms'],
                                                         ignore_directories=False,       case_sensitive=False)

    def on_created(self, event):
        print("Event created - % s." % event.src_path)
        GET_DATA(event.src_path)

def GET_DATA(filename):
    print("DATA FUNC:",filename)
    tdms_file = nptdms.TdmsFile.open(filename)
    group = tdms_file["Ramp 15"]
    #    all_groups = tdms_file.groups()
    channel = group["TorqueTransducer"]
    data = channel[:]
    print(group)
    print(channel)
    print(numpy.max(data))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    src_path = r"C:\PythonTargetDirectory"
    event_handler = Handler()
    observer = watchdog.observers.Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path=src_path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(60)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
else:
    while True:
        time.sleep(60)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've answered this myself!!

Put in a pause for the file to save correctly, 5 secs works well, before calling the GET_DATA function. Simples

```
def on_created(self, event):
    print("Event created - % s." % event.src_path)
    time.sleep(5)
    GET_DATA(event.src_path)
```

PS>
Ultimately this didnt work as the test ran over 8 minutes, and waited to be completed. However the raising and saving of the TDMS file was "watched" as 2 'modified' instances. So I waited for the second instance, before opening the file.

```
def on_modified(self, event):
    print("Watchdog received modified event - % s." % event.src_path)
    time.sleep(1)
    global x
    x =+1
    if x==2:
        GET_DATA(event.src_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file size is large, 5 seconds delay may not be sufficient.
Instead you can make a simple check to compare the file size repeatedly with a delay.
Once the file is created fully, file size remains constant, and you can continue with reading the file.

I found this info from below link. It also mentions other ways.
https://www.py4u.net/discuss/187495

```
def wait_till_file_is_created(self, source_path):
    historicalSize = -1
    while (historicalSize != os.path.getsize(source_path)):
        historicalSize = os.path.getsize(source_path)
        time.sleep(1) # Wait for one second

def on_created(self, event):
    print("Event created - % s." % event.src_path)   
    self.wait_till_file_is_created(event.src_path)
    GET_DATA(event.src_path)
```

Comment: I found this didnt work.. See above for how I solved it.